# How to drop collection from database in MongoDB using Mongo DB JAVA driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

The following commands were typed using mongo.exe client (assuming that the collection *coll* exists) :

```
> use database
switched to db database
>db.coll.drop()
True
```

How to perform db.coll.drop() using Mongo DB JAVA driver?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
DBCollection myCollection = db.getCollection("myCollection");
myCollection.drop();
```

Answer (score 12):

The current accepted answer would create a collection that did not previously exist and delete it, since getCollection creates one by the given name if it does not exist. It would be more efficient to check for existence first:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
if (db.collectionExists("myCollection")) {
    DBCollection myCollection = db.getCollection("myCollection");
    myCollection.drop();
}
```

Comment: What version of the driver are you using? I am using 3.3.0 and couldn't find the `collectionExists` method.

Comment: I don't know what I was using back then.... that method still exists in 3.3 and 3.4... here are the 3.4 api docs: http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/com/mongodb/DB.html#collectionExists-java.lang.String-