# String Mongo delete all files from GridFs

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

Using Spring Mongo is there a way of deleting multiple files from Mongo(stored with GridFS) all at once using only query or something similar? For example if I have in collection .files a field Language I want to be able to delete all entries from .files and also from .chunks in a single query. Not sure if this is possible in Mongo (outside Spring).

Tried to use GridFsTemplate but the delete method calls GridFS.remove method (code from Spring-Mongodb)

```
public void delete(Query query) {
    getGridFs().remove(getMappedQuery(query));
}
```

And this method gets all files in memory and then deletes them one by one:

```
 public void remove( DBObject query ){
    for ( GridFSDBFile f : find( query ) ){
        f.remove();
    }
}
void remove(){
    _fs._filesCollection.remove( new BasicDBObject( "_id" , _id ) );
    _fs._chunkCollection.remove( new BasicDBObject( "files_id" , _id ) );
}
```

UPDATE: from comments:

> Yes, you can't perform such kind of queries in MongoDB. Also, there is no direct way of deleting bunch of files in GridFS using both mongofiles command line tool and mongo java driver.

Comment: `*.files` and `*.chunks` are two separate collections. In MongoDB it is impossible to perform operations on two separate collections within the same query. At a minimum, this must be two queries: one for each collection. Also, you'd typically use your driver's built-in GridFS methods, if they're available (I'm not familiar with Spring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DBObject query;
    //write appropriate query
    List<GridFSDBFile> fileList = gfs.find(query);
    for (GridFSDBFile f : fileList)
    {
        gfs.remove(f.getFilename());
        // if you have not set fileName and
        // your _id is of ObjectId type, then you can use 
        //gfs.remove((ObjectId) file.getId());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what i'm looking for. It is a bad performance to delete this way 10k files for example. Sadly I think mongo does not offer the possibility of deleting both entries from collections directly in a query. (i.e. Delete * from .files, .chunks where file_id > 10)

Comment: Yes, you can't perform such kind of queries in MongoDB.  Also, there is no direct way of deleting bunch of files in GridFS using both mongofiles command line tool and mongo java driver.

Comment: If you have only GridFS files in your database and you want to delete all of them, you can drop the whole database.

Answer (score 3):

To remove an entire collection at once, you can perform one of these operations:

If your collection is a **MongoDB** collection, you can delete it with

```
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("db");
db.getCollection("MyCollectionName").drop();
```

If you are not certain collection named "MyCollectionName" exists, you should check that first, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26812074/10923897).

If your collection is a **GridFS** collection, you can delete it with

```
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("db");
db.getCollection("MyCollectionName.files").drop();
db.getCollection("MyCollectionName.chunks").drop();
```

This works, since GridFS collections consist of a `.files` and a `.chunks` collection behind the screens, and those are accessible (and removable) in the 'classic' way.